# Get one random record for each of 3 group

Tags: mysql

I have a table with questions from three categories.

I get one random question by using the following:

```
SELECT * FROM tblQuestions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

But the table also have a field called qCategory where there are 3 categories in total. What I want is the SQL query to get one question from each of the 3 categories (so 3 random questions in total).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can combine the results of three queries by using `UNION ALL`:

```
(SELECT * FROM tblQuestions WHERE qCategory='A' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM tblQuestions WHERE qCategory='B' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM tblQuestions WHERE qCategory='C' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Should this work for MySQL? I tried the query in phpMyAdmin, but got an error: "incorrect usage of UNION".

Comment: @user880980: Yes, it works... I just forgot the parentheses. See the update.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT * FROM tblQuestions ORDER BY RAND() GROUP BY qCategory
```